# Bash extract substring from a generic string

Tags: string, bash, substring

I have string such as

```
username/ticket-12345/feature
```

and i want to extract just

```
ticket-12345
```

from bash. the forrmat of this string could be anything.... e.g.

```
'my string ticket-12345'
```

and 'ticket' could be a mixture of lower case and upper case. 
Is this possible to do from bash? I've tried searching for this particular case but i can't seem to find an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a pure bash regex method:

```
re='[[:alpha:]]+-[0-9]+'

s='username/ticket-12345/feature'
[[ $s =~ $re ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
ticket-12345

s='my string ticket-12345'
[[ $s =~ $re ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
ticket-12345
```

Comment: Hmm. I may have hit "post" 15 seconds earlier, but I think you have the stronger answer; only functional difference between our approaches is whether `ticket` can be any alpha string, or can only consist of the letters `T`/`t`, `I`/`i`, `C`/`c`, `K`/`k`, and so forth

Comment: ...that said, it'd be better to change from `[A-Za-z]` to `[[:alpha:]]`, since the `A-Z` approach is collation-order/locale-dependent.

Comment: Yes that's right, probably this regex is too generic if OP wants only `ticket` in  mixed cases.

Comment: At the time of writing, i didn't actually need a generic method, but this is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The shell's built-in ERE (extended regular expression) support is adequate to the task:

```
ticket_re='[Tt][Ii][Cc][Kk][Ee][Tt]-[[:digit:]]+'
string='my string ticket-12345'

[[ $string =~ $ticket_re ]] && echo "Found ticket: ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
```

Comment: You can also use `nocasematch` with `ticket-[[:digit:]]+` to ignore the case of "ticket", although that becomes awkward if you need to limit its scope to just this one match.

Answer (score 1):

With the `-o` flag grep and its friends display only the found matches. You can use

```
egrep -io 'ticket-[0-9]+' file.txt
```

to find the tickets from your input text.

Comment: *nod*. Works (on most platforms, [`-o` being a non-POSIX extension](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html)), as-updated -- whether this is more appropriate than the pure bash method depends on usage context (`grep` can scan through a large file much more quickly, but if each call is evaluating only a single line, then it'll be far slower than the shell-builtin alternative on account of the overhead required to `fork` and `exec()` an external process).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: That's right, I will keep it and your solution in mind.